# Finding efficiently which points are in each pixel with Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D grid representing a set of pixels. For each pixel, I have the coordinates of the top left corner.

I also have a very long list of randomly distributed 2D points. I am looking for an efficient way of finding the indices of the points present in each pixel.

For the moment I have the following:

```
import numpy as np
xgrid = np.linspace(0,10,11)
ygrid = np.linspace(0,10,11)

X_random_points = np.random.rand(int(1e7))*10
Y_random_points = np.random.rand(int(1e7))*10

for iterationX in range(0,len(xgrid)-1):
    for iterationY in range(0,len(ygrid)-1):
        valuesInCube = (X_random_points<xgrid[iterationX]) & (X_random_points>xgrid[iterationX-1]) & (Y_random_points<ygrid[iterationY]) &(Y_random_points>ygrid[iterationY-1])
```

I was wondering if someone had an idea of how to make this quicker?

Comment: What is `valuesInCube` supposed to contain? Right now it's a mask that gets reset every time. Do you want a count or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a related approach that might still be useful. You can instead find which pixel each point belongs to. The functions `numpy.digitize` and `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d` are useful here. `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d` feels a little clumsy since it does more than just bin your points and requires you to give some values for each of your x,y points.

You should note that the bin numbering starts counting at `1` (not `0`).

```
x_p, y_p = np.digitize(X_random_points, xgrid), np.digitize(Y_random_points, xgrid)

# OR #

_, _, _, (x_p, y_p) = scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d(X_random_points, Y_random_points, np.zeros(len(X_random_points)), bins=(xgrid, ygrid), expand_binnumbers=True)
```

For a particular pixel, you can even find all points that belong to that pixel from `x_p` and `y_p`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.floor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html) to vectorize the whole operation and avoid looping entirely, as long as the separation between pixels is even in each direction. For your simple case, where `xgrid` and `ygrid` are integers, you can just do

```
X_random_points = ...
Y_random_points = ...
x_pixels = np.floor(X_random_points)
y_pixels = np.floor(Y_random_points)
```

If your pixels are not on an integer grid, you have to know the separation between them. In this case, I would recommend using `np.arange` instead of `np.linspace` to generate pixel locations:

```
delta_x, delta_y = 0.5, 0.5
xgrid = np.arange(0, 5.1, delta_x)
ygrid = np.arange(0, 5.1, delta_y)

X_random_points = np.random.rand(int(1e7)) * 5
Y_random_points = np.random.rand(int(1e7)) * 5

x_pixels = np.floor(X_random_points / delta_x)
y_pixels = np.floor(Y_random_points / delta_y)
```

You are really doing the same thing for the integer case, since both `delta_x` and `delta_y` are both `1` then.